# I am using VS10 and I get this error "Text-Overflow is not a known CSS property"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I have installed  *CSS 3 Intellisense Schema* and  *Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1*. VS still doesn't identify it as a valid property. What could be the problem?